# If the tubes are shipped in boxes of $1000$, how many wrong-sized tubes per box can doctors expect to find?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

The cross-section area of plastic tubing for use in pulmonary resuscitators in normally distributed with $\mu = 12.5mm^{2} $ and $\sigma = 0.2 mm^{2}$ . When the area is less than $12 mm^{2}$ or larger than $13 mm^{2}$, the tube does not fit properly. If the tubes are shipped in boxes of $1000$, how many wrong-sized tubes per box can doctors expect to find?

**Attempt**: we need to find the area when it is less than $12 mm^{2}$ or larger than $13 mm^{2}$, the tube does not fit properly.

Then using the above information and finding the area under the standard normal distribution together with the normal table , we have $P(X < 12 $ or $ X > 13) = P(X <12) + P(X > 13) = P(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{12-\mu}{\sigma}) + 1 -  P(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \leq \frac{13-\mu}{\sigma}) = P(Z < \frac{12-12.5}{0.2}) +  [1 -  P({Z} \leq \frac{13-12.5}{0.2})] = P(X < -2.5) + 1 - P(Z \leq 2.5) = 0.0062 + 1 - 0.9938 = 0.0124 $

Thus the number of wrong-sized tubes per box that doctors can expect to find is the probability times $100$ Thus, $100*0.0124 = 12.4$

Can anyone please verify this? Any help/feeback  would really help.
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is about right, but there are two errors that happen to cancel!

The probability a tube is bad (too big or too small) is roughly $2(0.0062)$, that is, $0.0124$. And you need to multiply by $1000$, not by $100$, giving expected value about $12.4$.

Comment: So, everything is fine until the last part? I need 1000*0.124 = 124? where did the 2 come from? The expected value is 12.4 if multiply by 100,but 124 if by 1000.

Comment: No, I said there are two errors. The probability a tube is bad is about $0.0124$, **not** $0.124$. And you multiply $0.0124$ by $1000$, getting $12.4$.

Comment: You are right? It was typo. Then we get 0.0062 + 1 -0.9938 = 0.0124. Then 1000*0.0124 = 12.4

Comment: The $2(0.0.0062)$ comes from the fact that $12$ and $13$ are symmetrical about the mean, so the areas of the left tail and of the right tail are equal, both $0.0062$. Adding them is the same as multiplying by $2$. This replaces your somewhat more complicated calculation, where you lost a $0$.

Comment: Symmetrical about the mean, so instead of (1 + 0.9938) I can use 0.0062?

Comment: "Instead of" $1-0.9938$  you can, without calculation, use $0.0062$. You have a typo, "+" in the comment. You had it right in the original post.